# Deserialization behaviour on KStream-KTable left Join

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

Using Kafka Streams DSL I deserialize an event into a bean that I then wrap into an "EventCarrier".  A KStream processes the event.

The EventCarrier allows me to record any exception that occurs during processing.  I branch the stream into success and failure streams based on the presence or absence of an exception.

The model works well until I LeftJoin my stream to a KTable.  At this point it seems Kafka discards the EventCarrier and creates a new one by deserializing the original event again.  Any excepotion that had been store in the original EventCarrier is lost.

Is desrialization to be expected in this scenario, or am I doing something wrong?

```java
 KStream<String, EventCarrier> notificationStream[] = myStream
    .filter((key, carrier) -> shouldNotify(carrier.getEvent()))
    .selectKey((key, carrier) -> carrier.getEvent().getGuid())
    .peek((key, carrier) -> carrier.recordException(new Exception("Ouch!!")))
    .peek((key, carrier) -> System.out.println("1:" + carrier.getException()))
    .leftJoin(notificationsTable, (carrier, notification) -> 
         recordWhetherNotificationFound(carrier, notification))
    .peek((key, carrier) -> System.out.println("2:" + carrier.getException()))
```

and the method

```java
    private ProductEventCarrier recordWhetherNotificationFound(ProductEventCarrier carrier, NotificationEvent notification) {
            carrier.setNotificationFound(nonNull(notification));
        return carrier;
    }
```

In the above code, the exception gets printed as expected in the first println, but is null in the second.

Comment: "At this point it seems Kafka discards the EventCarrier and creates a new one by deserializing the original event again." -- not sure what you mean by this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hi.  I mean that when the left-join is executed, I see the raw event being deserialized again creating a new EventCarrier instance, and this instance is passed as the "carrier" parameter into the ValueJoiner.  Any state I had previoulsy built up in the EventCarrier (such as exceptions) is lost.

Comment: What is unclear to me it, where the deserialization happens? If you have a stream-side record that is processed, it only does a lookup into the table (the table would deserialize the "notification" from the store though). Can you tell which part within Kafka Streams is calling the deserialization of your stream record?

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  It looks like the join setp is causing the deserialization.  If I remove that step, the deserialization is only invoked once (as expected, when the event is initially polled from the topic) and state added to the EventCarrier is retained throughout the processing.  I can understand the deserialization of the notification, as you mention, but the EventCarrier seems to be getting deserialized too.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and share the call trace?